# Change color of background with xlswwriter in an existing sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I want to change color of background with xlsxwritter :

```
        for row in range(rowCount, 200):
        if (row % 2) == 0:
            for col in range(10):
                worksheet.write_string(row, col, "", cell_format_odd)
        else:
            for col in range(10):
                worksheet.write_string(row, col, "", cell_format_even)
```

But that erase content of my cells :/
How to avoid that erase on my existing text ?

Comment: your content is overwritten by the empty string you are passing in the write_string(..) . check this out https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_string

Answer (score 0):

`xlsxwriter` does not support changing cell properties retroactively.
You need to keep track of your row number on-the-fly and apply the formatting when writing the actual data.